# Possible to avoid "Add-in Blocked Untrusted web add-ins from the Internet are blocked by default"

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, office-js

Users are getting an error message when opening Excel workbooks that have a web add-in manifest pre-inserted into them, instead of getting prompted to trust the add-in.

**Message:**
"ADD-IN BLOCKED Untrusted web add-ins from the Internet are blocked by default. This add-in is from \\myhost.us.mycompany.com\web-addins."

**Environment:**

- Windows, Excel 2016 desktop.
- Our web add-in (fka Office add-in) is hosted on a non-MSFT server.
- The catalog location hosting the manifest is on a Windows file share.  Call it \\myhost.us.mycompany.com\web-addins.

**Research:**

- Googling for the first sentence in the error message returns 0 hits.
- Looked for a setting in Excel > File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Add-in Catalogs.  Nothing found to override this blocking behavior.

**Question:** Is there a way to avoid this message, other than adding the trusted catalog setting to every end-user's Excel configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure trusted catalogs automatically across an organization, you can set group policy using use the [Office Customization Tool and the Office Administrative Templates](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030).

The settings for this feature can be found at:
Microsoft Office 2016 > Security Settings > Trust Center > Trusted Catalogs. We also support these settings for Office 2013.

[image]

The 3 relevant template settings to enable are:

- Allow Unsecure web add-ins and Catalogs
- Trusted Catalog Location #1
- Default Shared Folder Location

And here's an example for how you would complete the Default Shared Folder Location setting:

[image]

And as Philip's answer explains, deployment via a network share is not the recommended solution, but you can still use my instructions above if there's some reason why you want to deploy it this way.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This should help my customers deploy the add-in throughout their enterprise, without having individual users need to get involved with trusting the catalog location.  Regarding "deployment via network share is not the recommended solution" - in this case, the customers don't use SharePoint. Until MSFT provides another catalog option (web server!), this is the best I can offer them.  FWIW I have unconfirmed reports that if a shortname is used (eg. \\host\share not \\host.domain.com\share), the add-in is not blocked. Perhaps Excel doesn't consider that "from the Internet".

Answer (score 0):

The general way to make apps available within your business is to publish them to an internal App Catalog, more information can be found here - https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish-task-pane-and-content-add-ins-to-an-add-in-catalog and 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219429.aspx

If you want to publish them via a network share, then yes you would have to push out this setting to each end user individually.

Comment: Thanks. My customers don't use SharePoint, so necessarily have to use the network share.